# Parse HTML tables for varying number of columns

Tags: regex, perl, html-table

I need to parse monitoring data from a HTML table for logging purposes.

There are multiple tables in the HTML document without any identifiers, so identifying the correct TR requires improvising.

Particular row of interest is:

```
<TR>
    <TD>Signal to Noise Ratio</TD>
    <TD>35 dB</TD>
    <TD>35 dB</TD>
    <!-- MORE TDs continue here... -->
</TR>
```

Thus, the identifier/constant that can be used is "Signal to Noise Ratio" string in TR to identify the correct TD's of interest in the document.

The number of `TD` elements following the first that contains the identifying string in this row is variable. I need to store all integers from those elements as variables, similar to this:

```
my %data;
my @keys = qw(SNR1 SNR2 SNR3 SNR4);

my $content = LWP::Simple::get("http://192.168.100.1/cmSignalData.htm")
    or die "Couldn't get it!";

if ( $content =~ /<TD>(.+?) dB<\/TD>/ ) {
    $data{SNR1} = $1;
} 

for (@keys) {
    print "$_:" . $data{$_} . " ";
}
print "\n";
```

And then parse other `TR` elements in other tables in the exactly same pattern.

Comment: You're saying that you have some HTML data that contains multiple `table` elements, one of which has a `td` element that contains the text `Signal to Noise Ratio`, and you want the contents of all following `td` elements in the same `tr`. Is that correct? Can the `table` elements  be inside one another? It would help enormously if you could publish the complete HTML, perhaps on pastebin or similar

Comment: Exactly, correct. No, table elements are not nested. Full HTML is here: http://pastebin.com/73H5peKW

Comment: @DominiqueBal: welcome in 90's

Comment: That's excellent. Thank you. I will take a look tomorrow if you don't get an answer in the mean time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the values you want with an XPath query, since you are looking for all the following `td` nodes at the same level after a specific `td` node.

Here's an example using the [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm) module:

```perl
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse_file("yourfile.html");

my @snr = $tree->findvalues('//td[.="Signal to Noise Ratio"]/following-sibling::td');
$tree->delete;

@snr = map /^(\d+)/, @snr;
print join(', ', @snr);
```

XPath is a language to query the tree representation of an HTML/XML document, the [DOM (Document Object Model) tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html).

Query details:

```php
//   # anywhere in the tree (*)
td   # a `td` element with the following "predicate" (embedded in square brackets):

[.="Signal to Noise Ratio"] # predicate: the text content of the current node (figured
                            # by a dot) is exactly "Signal to Noise Ratio"

/following-sibling::td # 'following-sibling::' is a kind of selector called "axis"
                       # that selects all nodes with the same parent node after the
                       # current element.
                       # 'td' selects only `td` elements in this node-set.
```

<sup>*(*) if you want you can be more explicit. Instead of using `//td`, you can describe the full path from the root element `/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td`*</sup>

This approach needs to build the document tree to be able to query it. It is not a fast approach, but the main advantage is that you use the HTML structure instead of a wild text approach.

Note that you could avoid the array `map` to extract the digits at the beginning of each items. XPath has several string functions including `substring-before`:

```
//td[.="Signal to Noise Ratio"]/following-sibling::td/substring-before(text(), " dB")
```

If performance is important, you can try another approach with a pull parser like [`HTML::TokeParser::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/HTML-TokeParser-Simple-3.16/lib/HTML/TokeParser/Simple.pm). This is less handy to write, but it's faster because there's no DOM tree to build, and you will save memory because you can read the HTML file as a stream and stop to read it when you want without to load the whole file in memory.

Comment: This is fantastic and very flexible, thanks! This prints "value, value, value". How do I make it print "SNR1: value, SNR2: value, SNR3: value"? Note the SNR string with incremental number before. This would make it easier for further manipulation. Thanks!

Comment: @DominiqueBal: you can use map to add "SNRn" to each items.

Comment: The explicit `$1` in your `map` is superfluous, because the block is executed in list context, and a regex match will return a list of the captures. All that is necessary is `@snr = map /(\d+)/, @snr`

Answer (score 2):

**Do not parse HTML with Regex. Use a HTML parser.**

There are several HTML parser modules available on CPAN. My favorite is Mojo::DOM. You can use it like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $HTML = <<"EOF";
<table>
<TR>
<TD>Signal to Noise Ratio</TD>
<TD>35 dB</TD>
<TD>35 dB</TD>
</TR>
</table>
EOF

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $HTML );

if ($dom->at('tr td')->text() eq 'Signal to Noise Ratio'){
   for my $e ($dom->find('td')->each) {
      if($e->text() =~ /(\d+)\sdB/){
          print $1."\n";
      }
   }
}
```

For a 8 minute video tutorial on `Mojo::DOM` and `Mojo::UserAgent` check out [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

Comment: Thank you very much. Makes sense to parse instead of Regex-ing. I preferred the other poster's solution with XPath but thanks a lot for putting Mojo::DOM into my attention as I'll be using it for other scripts.

Comment: The issue I have with `Mojo::DOM` is that it accepts only CSS selectors, which are ideal for expressing collections of elements to receive a given style, but not so good for general navigation of the HTML data tree. The biggest deficiency is the lack of any way to define the text content of the required elements, which therefore needs some Perl codeto find the `Signal to Noise Ratio` `<td>` element. In XPath, all that is required is `//td[.="Signal to Noise Ratio"]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using *Mojolicious*. It pulls the HTML directly from your pastebin repository

The `for` loop iterates over all the rows in all tables. Inside it, the `@columns` array is set to the text content of all the columns (`<td>` elements) in the row

The first element is checked, firstly that it exists, and secondly that it is equal to `Signal to Noise Ratio`. If so then the global array `@snr` is set to the decimal numbers in the remainder of `@columns`, and `last` stops the search for the required row

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Mojo;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $dom = $ua->get('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=73H5peKW')->res->dom;

my @snr;

for my $row ( $dom->find('table tr')->each ) {
    my @columns = $row->find('td')->map('text')->each;
    next unless @columns;
    if ( shift @columns eq 'Signal to Noise Ratio' ) {
        @snr = map /(\d+)/, @columns;
        last;
    }
}

say "@snr";
```

#### output

```
35 35 34 34 34 34 34 34
```